# htaccess rewrite rule securing directory with cookie

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cookies, mod-rewrite

I have been trying to use a rewrite rule to block downloading of files in a directory based on whether art not there is a cookie set with "is_logged_in" true.  I'm very confused.
The name of the cookie is "qts" but the value inside the cookie is "is_logged_in".
I've tried a whole bunch of different rules. I've also tried putting the .htaccess in the directory in question as well as the top directory.  Nothing seems to work. I must admit I'm not really understanding the rules, so i'd appreciate help.
I should note that I am not able to change to php script to protect the directory. It would require changing the app and I am not able to do that. I also can't put the files in a directory outside above public_html because the app only looks in directories below public_html. Thanks so much for any help you are willing to give.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /directory_in_question
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png!jpg)$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !is_logged_in=true [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?con=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule
```

I've tried a whole bunch of different scripts. I'm wanting the rewrite rule to prevent downloading files from the directory_in_question if the cookie value is_logged_in is not set.

Comment: Is it only `.png` and `.jpg` files you wish to protect? Why are you rewriting the request to `/index.php?con=<URL>`?

Comment: No, I want to ptotect everything in that directory but this was just to start to see if I could make it work. I thought I was sending it away to the main index page which will cause it to ask for a login. Like I said. I have no idea what I’m doing here ;)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteBase /directory_in_question
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png!jpg)$
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !is_logged_in=true [NC]
> RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?con=$1 [L,QSA]
> ```

There are a few issues here. The main problems that will prevent this from working as intended include:

- `\.(png!jpg)$` - Regex alternation uses the vertical pipe character (`|`), not an exclamation mark (`!`). The `!` is seen as a literal character so this regex never matches and the rule is not processed. However, if you want to block everything (as stated in comments) then this condition is not required.
- `is_logged_in=true` - This is checking for a cookie named `is_logged_in` with the value `true` (string). However, you said in the question that the cookie is called `qts` with a value `is_logged_in`. (So why not try `qts=is_logged_in`?) Therefore this is going to fail. (Although since the regex is negated, with a `!` prefix, the *condition* will always be successful.) However, you also need to check for cookie delimiters (ie. `;` - semicolon), since the `Cookie` header contains *all* cookies sent from the client, otherwise you could potentially catch too much (eg. a cookie called `somethingqts`).
- `^([^/]+)/?$` - This regex is only matching URLs with a single path segment. If this `.htaccess` file is in the root then it's going to fail to match the `directory_in_question` that you want to block access. This *pattern* would be OK if the `.htaccess` file is *inside* the `directory_in_question`. But if you simply want to block everything (including any subdirectories) then it can be further simplified.

Other minor points:

- The `RewriteBase` directive is not doing anything here. All this directive does is override the directory-prefix that is added back on relative path *substitutions* at the end of the rewriting process. You have no relative path *substitutions*. (`/index.php?con=$1` is a root-relative substitution.)
- `/index.php?con=$1` - This rewrites the request to a `/index.php` in the root (in the hope it would trigger a login). This is specific to your system so whether this is the correct course of action I don't know. However, if you simply want to block the request then serve a "403 Forbidden" response instead (with the `F` flag).

Try the following instead, in a `.htaccess` file in the directory you want to block (not the root):

```
# /directory_in_question/.htaccess

RewriteEngine On

# Block all requests if cookie not set
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(^|\s|;)qts=is_logged_in($|\s|;)
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

NB: No need for the `<IfModule>` wrapper.

Comment: Well it doesn't work.  Maybe iv'e got this all wrong.  The app creates the session like so: $_SESSION["qts"] = array(); is that not the name that the cookie has. I know the key I'm looking for is "is_logged_in" What am I misunderstanding here. Sorry to be so dense. I corrected a type, I put the name wrong , but ive enter the correct one in the script.

Comment: I think I've confused sessions with cookies. Is there a way to do this using the Session variables

Comment: @Baxterdmutt No, `$_SESSION["qts"]` is a session variable/property - not a cookie! The session cookie (default name `PHPSESSID` on PHP) is simply an _id_ for the session that is stored entirely server-side. The values of the session properties are only available to your server-side script (eg. PHP).

Comment: @Baxterdmutt "Is there a way to do this using the Session variables" - No, `.htaccess` (ie. Apache) cannot read the properties of the PHP session.  You would need to create an additional cookie, outside of the PHP session. (But also, cookies are trivial to "fake", so anything based on a static cookie is not particularly secure. Although many do do exactly that.)

Comment: Well thanks. I realized all that I I was talking to you. I’m sorry to have wasted your time. At least I’ve learned a bit about sessions and cookies. I’m not good enough to re-write the scripts in this app. I’ll go looking for a different solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @Baxterdmutt You're welcome. Have a look at the HTTP request headers (Network tab in the browser dev tools) to see what your browser is sending to the server. What you see there is all you can access in Apache/`.htaccess`. If any cookies are being sent then they are present in the `Cookie` header - which can then be parsed to examine particular name/value pairs (as in my answer above).

Comment: @Baxterdmutt Once you have 15+ rep remember to come back and upvote answers you found helpful, thanks :)